# Программа не дает удалить папки

Tags: c#

Написал на c# программу, удаляющую по определенному пути определенные папки.

```
new DirectoryInfo(directories[i]).Delete(true);
```

Однако, не удается удалить ни одну папку, т.к. получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
System.IO.IOException: "Отказано в доступе по пути "
```

Что в данном случае можно предпринять?

Comment: Например, отловить в try...catch и пропустить эту папку.

Comment: Или же запрашивать права администратора при запуске приложения

Comment: А вручную эти папки удаляются? А программа не с какой-то из этих папок как текущей запускается? Причин много может быть

Comment: 1)Директория может быть не пустая2)В ней могут быть файлы которые используются в данный момент каким-то процесом   3)атрибуты директории readonly 4) разрешение на удаление данной директории нету у вашего пользователя

Comment: Если директория не пустая, как ее можно удалить? Пользователь текущий - админ. В ручную папки удаляются.